# SQL Geography data type, how to use the gibberish it contains?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sqlgeography

I'm looking at the sql geography data type and it doesn't seem very intuitive and I'm just not finding a lot of good (or rather "easy to understand") information on it. For example (taken 'partially' from a site I found talking about it sparsely):

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[visitorLocationInfo](id, test)
VALUES(3, 
  geography::STPointFromText('POINT(55.9523783996701 -3.2051030639559)', 4326)
);
```

I get that the first is lat, the second long but what's that third value for (`4326`) and how am I supposed to work with the results it puts in???

```
id  latitude    longitude   zip     city    state   country test
3   NULL        NULL        NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    0xE6100000010CF9FF3F130DA409C0FDFF0F89E7F94B40
```

That long number isn't very readable...

Maybe I just need someone taking 5 minutes to give me the nickel tour?

Comment: From checking out [STPointFromText](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.types.sqlgeography.stpointfromtext.aspx) it looks like the `4326` is the spatial reference ID. Sadly I don't know how to answer the other parts of your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The geography data type is implemented as a CLR type. Meaning that it acts like an object from the programming world. As such, you can call [all sorts of methods](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb933802.aspx) on it. What you're seeing is the hexadecimal representation of the object.

And in response to your question regarding distances and such, you're right. If you have a table with a column of the geography type, you can do something like:

```
declare @g geography = 
    geography::STPointFromText(
      'POINT(55.9523783996701 -3.2051030639559)', 4326
    ).STBuffer(5);

select *
from dbo.yourTable
where gCol.STIntersects(@g) = 1
```

Which says "get me all of the rows in dbo.yourTable where the some part of the geography object contained in the column gCol is within 5 meters of 55.9523783996701 -3.2051030639559".

Comment: Thanks. You covered that *really* well. I have one last question. In my example, after latitude and longitude, the number 4326... what is that parameter for? The example I found the code one didn't explain that.

Comment: It's the spatial reference id (SRID). Essentially, many organizations over the years have described the oblate spheroid that we live on in different ways. You can view all the ones that SQL Server knows about in sys.spatial_reference_systems. I've used 4326 for everything I've ever done, but YMMV. Lastly, two geography instances need to have the same SRID in order to be compared. Think of it like collation is for text data.

Comment: Thanks for the great explanation. To be sure I understood though: In short, it doesn't matter TOO much so long as I use the same one and can use pretty much any of the ones listed in the spatial reference systems reference. Right?

Comment: From what I understand, yes. For whatever reason, they tend to use 4236 in all the example code so that one seems like a safe bet.

Answer (score 2):

I am not familiar with this, but [it seems you can call `ToString`](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/f2a5aafd-ef7a-456c-b380-bc6d7e8c370f/how-to-convert-geography-back-to-polygon-or-array-of-point?forum=sqlspatial) on the column to get the text representation back:

```
select test.ToString()
from   tableName
```

Comment: This is what I was initially looking for so I'll mark this as "answer" because I can use it. (Thank you) I really really want to understand it though because the geography datatype can use distance filtering based on a spherical "plane" without really having to apply a haversine function...